# PCA-algorithm dependence on number of principal components.

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, regression, principal-component-analysis

Consider the following idea: we have $(X,Y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times (d+k)}$ - initial data. Let's call $\bar{X} = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i$ (the same for $\bar{Y}$). We want to predict $y$ by $x$ using the following algorithm:

1. We select $r$ first principal components $u_1 \ldots u_r$ of matrix $Z = [XY]$. Let $U$ be matrix based on $u_i$ (as rows). Let $U_X$ and $U_Y$ be the part correspond to $X$ and $Y$.
2. We reduce dimension using following map: $(x,y) \to \lambda = (\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_r)$: $$
   \lambda = U^\top (z^\top - (\bar{X} \bar{Y})^\top)
   $$

And we also have an inverse map:

$$
\begin{array}
\tilde{\tilde{x}}(\lambda) = \bar{X} + U_X\lambda\\
\tilde{y}(\lambda) = \bar{Y} + U_Y\lambda
\end{array}
$$

So in order to get a prediction we do two steps:

$$
\lambda^* = \arg \min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^r} \|\tilde{x}(\lambda) - x\|_2^2\\
y^* = \bar{Y} + U_Y \lambda^*
$$

I need to compute value of $\lambda^*$ and $y^*$ based on $x, X,Y, U$. It seems to be pretty easy:

$$
\lambda^*(x) = \text{arg}\min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^r} \|\bar{X}  + U_X \lambda - x \|^2 \\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\|\bar{X}  + U_X \lambda - x \|^2 = 2U_X^\top (\bar{X}  + U_X \lambda - x ) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda^* = (U_X^\top U_X)^{-1}U_X^\top(x - \bar{X}) \Rightarrow \\
y^*(x) = \bar{Y} + U_Y (U^\top_X U_X)^\top U^\top_X (x - \bar{X})
$$

But it says that the answer should depend on $r \le d$ or $r > d$. I don't see the reason. Maybe  the problem is following: if we select $r > d$ components then each $u_i = (u_{X,i} u_{Y,i})$ and if $r > d$ then X part is linear dependent of each other? However, even though I don't see how does it affect the steps. Any hints?

Comment: Is there some information about what r or d is? Is there some extra interdependence in the data of some subspace dependent on r and d?

Comment: @mathreadler $d$ is the dimension of $x_i \in X$ and $r$ is the number of first principal components selected. No independence, that's just a regular train sample $(X,Y)$.

Comment: When you say "it says that the answer should depend on r\leq d", what is "it"?